# Writing dynamically-sized arrays to file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, file-io

I am trying to write ASCII data to a text file in the following format:

```
            Time            Heat Flux       ...
           0.023                1.793       ...
               .
               .
               .
```

The text header comes from a list of tags with dimension *1 x n* and the numeric data with dimension *m x n*. I usually print this information when I know the number of rows and columns *a priori* in this manner:

```
# ... open file object, etc.

# Print header
print('%16s \t %16s' % ('Time', 'Heat Flux'), file=fileObject)

for ii in range(0, len(heatFlux):
    print('%16.3f \t %16.3f' % (heatFlux[ii][0], heatFlux[ii][1]), file=fileObject)
```

I want to have generic code that allows me to write these files with a dynamically-sized array (in terms of number of columns). I've tried to generate a string and insert the tags and spaces, which I then write to file, but I am not sure how to "format-print" the string itself.

For example, I was trying

```
tagHeader = []

for tag in keyTags:
    tagHeader = tagHeader + tag + '\t'
# ...
print(tagHeader, file=fileObject)
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list with the header and a 2D data structure you can do something like this:

```
def table(header, data):
    print('\t'.join(['%16s'] * len(header)) % tuple(header))
    for row in data:
        print('\t'.join(['%16.3f'] * len(header)) % tuple(row))
```

Here are some tests:

```
header1 = ['Time', 'Heat Flux']
header2 = ['Time', 'Heat Flux', 'New col']
header3 = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']

data1 = [[uniform(-10, 10) for _ in range(len(header1))] for _ in range(randint(2, 10))]
data2 = [[uniform(-10, 10) for _ in range(len(header2))] for _ in range(randint(2, 10))]
data3 = [[uniform(-10, 10) for _ in range(len(header3))] for _ in range(randint(2, 10))]

table(header1, data1)
table(header2, data2)
table(header3, data3)
```

Output:

```
        Time           Heat Flux
       7.037              -1.528
       8.058               5.649
        Time           Heat Flux             New col
      -9.590               4.846              -4.024
      -8.597               9.718              -8.174
       9.260              -0.947              -6.675
       3.401              -5.101               8.323
       0.099              -6.582               3.951
        This                  is                   a                test
      -2.126              -0.678               4.782              -7.849
      -9.007              -0.019              -4.402               8.017
      -7.399              -7.617               6.235               9.320
      -0.486              -5.304              -4.723               1.946
       2.743              -2.150              -6.779              -2.099
      -7.499              -2.618              -9.918               0.674
       8.912              -6.648              -7.865              -0.101
       0.682              -0.414               7.677               7.167
      -3.105              -6.562               6.970              -2.147
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. THANKS!